# Passing values to Construtor

Tags: java

```
package org.apache.wicket.examples.guestbook;

import java.util.Date;  
import org.apache.wicket.IClusterable;

public class Comment implements IClusterable {
    private String text;
    private Date date = new Date();

    public Comment() {
    }

    public Comment(final Comment comment) {
        this.text = comment.text;
        this.date = comment.date;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[Comment date = " + date + ", text = " + text + "]";
    }
}
```

Why does the other construtor do here? 
Why the `Comment comment` is declared as `final`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `final` there is optional in your case. In some projects/companies there is this rule that all method and constructor parameters are declared final.

The idea is that you should not be able to give the `comment` variable another value.

About the first question ("Why does the other construtor do here?"): this constructor is a so-called "copy-constructor". It gets an existing comment and creates a new instance with the same content.

Comment: I didn't understand your last sentence. No "new instance" is created at all... The reference is passed by value.

Comment: A constructor always creates a new instance.

Comment: I see. I thought you were still talking about the use of final.

Comment: aha. It's about the first question. I'll rephrase a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two constructors: one that initializes both the date and the text given a Comment object, and another that leaves the members uninitialized (therefore requiring the use of the setters to initialize them).

The *final* qualifier has no effect at all for the caller of the constructor. It only states that the method implementation doesn't assign the argument reference a new value. Note that even if it did, the caller would not be aware of it because java always passes parameters by value.

I suspect that the origin of this copy constructor pattern is C++, where *const* can be used to prevent modifying the **state** of the other object. With java's *final* this is not the case. You can freely modify the data members of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [final keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) in java. Unless you assign a new value to `final Comment comment` it will not give any error

Answer (score 0):

Other Constructors are used to initialize  the object when they are passed with their equivalent arguments , and final is used so that it can't be changed later in your code.